# Custom display of time series data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I want to transform a normal indexed time series dataframe into a dataframe that uses the hour atribute for the index, but displays the days data in the columns. Let's look at an example.

I have a df that looks like this:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2014-12-12 16:00:00  2001.00  2001.50  1999.75  2001.00
2014-12-12 16:05:00  2001.00  2001.75  2001.00  2001.25
2014-12-12 16:10:00  2001.00  2001.25  2000.00  2000.00
2014-12-12 16:15:00  2000.00  2000.50  1998.50  1999.00
2014-12-12 16:20:00  1998.75  1999.75  1998.75  1999.00
2014-12-13 16:00:00  1999.00  1999.25  1997.75  1998.75
2014-12-13 16:05:00  1998.75  1999.25  1996.75  1997.00
2014-12-13 16:10:00  1996.75  1998.75  1996.75  1998.75
2014-12-13 16:15:00  1998.75  1999.00  1998.00  1999.00
2014-12-13 16:20:00  1998.75  1999.00  1996.50  1997.50
```

And I want to transform it into this:

Note: The numbers are just the output of df['Close'].diff():

```
                     2014-12-12    2014-12-13
16:00:00 - 16:05:00     0.25         -1.75
16:05:00 - 16:10:00    -1.25          1.75
16:10:00 - 16:15:00    -1.00          0.25
16:15:00 - 16:20:00     0.00         -1.50
```

I think I could brute force a solution, but I would like to know if there's a cool trick (perhaps a Groupby) to do what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pivot table

```
df['date'] = map(lambda x: x.date(), df.index)
df['time'] = map(lambda x: x.time(), df.index)

sol = df.pivot('time', 'date', 'Close')
```